# Commands are disabled in WPF application when data source is empty

Tags: wpf, menu, command, toolbar

I have a simple WPF with a menu, a toolbar and a ListView in a GridView. The menu and toolbar actions are bound to commands.
I have `<CommandBinding>` that defines when commands should be executed (`CanExecute`). Some commands, such as "Create New Item" should always be executed, so they are bound to a "`e.CanExecute = true;`" function.

However, when the user selects all items in the list using Ctrl-A, and then presses Delete, my application runs a BackgroundWorker that deletes the items from the server and then sets the ItemsSource of the list view to the new data collection, which is empty.

This sometimes causes all commands in the menu and toolbar to be disabled. Note that their keyboard shortcuts still work, but the actions are disabled in the menu and toolbar.

This doesn't always happen, and I failed to find a rule to when it does happen.

Did anyone run into a similar behavior or has any idea what might cause it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I'll try, but it won't be simple.
First of all, the problem doesn't always recreate. Second, I don't know what part of the code is in change for it, but I don't want to post my entire code. I'll have to try minimize it, while being able to recreate the problem with this minimized code.

Comment: I just thought this would just ring a bell to someone who could point me to the right direction, even without the code. Obviously, I can switch to not working with commands, but with simple event handlers, but commands seems to be the right way to go.

Comment: Please post the code for the BackgroundWorker. It seems like it is affecting the UI thread somehow... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without code it may be hard. It looks like `CanExecute()` is not called. Set breakpoint in it and check. I assume you are using `RoutedCommands`. If yes, the problem may appear because `MenuItem.CommandTarget` is not set, and WPF tries to find `CommandBindings` somewhere up the tree, beyond your actual command bindings. If this is the case, set `CommandTarget` to proper value. Also you may want to call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` and see what happens.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't set MenuItem.CommandTarget for any of my MenuItems (I didn't know about this property). When the problem occurs, I assume the focus is on a control that can't handle these commands. However, I fail to recreate the problem now (as I said, it intermitent). What should I set the MenuItem.CommandTarget to be for commands like ApplicationCommands.New?

Comment: You can leave it. Just make sure there is a command binding for this command somewhere up enough in the visual tree (e.g. in the main window). So whenever CanExecute is requested WPF can find your bindings and handler...